# How to package other python scripts which are imported in one main python script in pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So i have one main python script: **Run.py** in Directory: **C:/python/project1**

I have 8 other python scripts in directory **C:/python/project1/Recov**

The 8 scripts are imported in the Run.py script.

Now when i run **pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico .\Run.py**

It does not include those 8 other scripts into the exe. How can i package those 8 scripts along with the main script into exe?

Comment: use other files as separate module and import them to your `Run.py`

Comment: Yes i am importing them in Run.py. But still they are not getting packaged.

Comment: put all of them in same folder and run pyinstaller

Comment: One could have a look at the `-p` / `--paths` argument https://pyinstaller.org/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of your script in the same folder. If you are importing them in the main script on which you are using pyinstaller, it will bundle those files.

Also open cmd in the directory and run

```
pyinstaller -F -w -i app.ico Run.py
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think the problem is something else. I am trying something else if that works i'll let you know.

Comment: it will be very helpful if you provide some example or the error it showing

Comment: Got it to work. Some internal function was creating error which i was not catching. Thanks

Comment: also use `-D` or `--onedir` to keep tracks of everything that has been packeged by pyinstaller

Comment: explanation of the -F, -w, -i please??

Comment: see this https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#options